# RX590/System Crashes Under Load Pop!_OS 19.10

Tags: drivers, crash, amd-graphics, amd

I've recently built a new PC:

Motherboard: B450 Tomahawk CPU: Ryzen 7 2700x GPU: RX590 FatBoy RAM: 2x16 Corsair LPX PSU: Seasonic FOCUS 550 80+ Gold HDD: Seagate BaraCuda 2TB SSD: Kingston 240GB A400 SATA 3 2.5" Case: Fractal Design Meshify C ATX

I'm able to play a variety of games for 10-40 minutes before the system just "stops." At first, connection to my monitors would cease, but the audio would continue to play. In some games it loops, in others the soundtrack continues to play. Though, if I'm using Discord or Spotify, they continue to play as normally.

I have since updated my BIOS in anticipation that it would fix the problem, but the only difference is that audio cuts out now as well. Moreover, the screen flashes a color before my monitors lose connection. I don't think my GPU has any thermal problems, considering it does this while 55-70C.

I come here as I'm not entirely sure if its my drivers, which are the open source AMD drivers that come in the kernel. I'd appreciate if anyone knows what further direction I should take in troubleshooting or solving this problem.

I have previously asked on another forum, and they've requested the following information to try and help me. I assume it would be of some use to others as well. I have performed a memtest and passed 4/4.

Additional Information: Output of free -h:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           31Gi       2.1Gi        27Gi        92Mi       1.6Gi        28Gi
Swap:         4.0Gi          0B       4.0Gi
```

Output of sudo sysctl vm.swappiness:

```
vm.swappiness = 10
```

Output of ls -al /var/crash:

```
total 66088
drwxrwxrwt  2 root   root       4096 Nov 29 09:43 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root   root       4096 Oct 29 15:33 ..
-rw-r-----  1 root   root      27259 Nov 28 18:44 _usr_bin_add-apt-repository.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 aldats aldats    91207 Nov 28 18:57 _usr_bin_nautilus.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 gdm    gdm     2184844 Nov 28 22:29 _usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.118.crash
-rw-r-----  1 root   root    4853601 Nov 29 09:43 _usr_share_radeon-profile_radeon-profile.0.crash
-rw-r-----  1 aldats aldats  6138237 Nov 29 09:36 _usr_share_radeon-profile_radeon-profile.1000.crash
-rw-r-----  1 aldats aldats 54361237 Nov 28 21:32 _usr_share_spotify_spotify.1000.crash
```